# Why isn't backdropFilter available in CSSStyleDeclaration?

Tags: css, typescript

The following code is not valid under the error:

`Property 'backdropFilter' does not exist on type 'CSSStyleDeclaration'.`

```
const modal = document.createElement('div')
modal.style.backdropFilter = '??'
```

Is there an explanation to why isn't https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter available in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently this property does not be considered as a normal case, but a special case, since it's not be supported in all version of firefox, you can keep tracing this issue: [backdropFilter missing from CSSStyleDeclaration #1118](https://githubmemory.com/repo/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1118)